# select tag inside ngFor - ngModel does not selects according to the value

Tags: html, angular

select dropdown inside ngFor is not pre-selecting values based on ngModel.
Here is the related component and html code:

```
testArr = [
    {
        id : '1',
        value: 'one'
    },
    {
        id : '2',
        value: 'two'
    },
    {
        id : '3',
        value: 'three'
    },
    {
        id : '4',
        value: 'four'
    }
];

testVal = [
    {
        id : '3',
        value : 'three'
    },
    {
        id : '4',
        value : 'four'
    },
    {
        id : '2',
        value : 'two'
    },
];

<tr *ngFor="let t of testVal">
    <select name = "test" [(ngModel)] = "t.id">
        <option *ngFor="let x of testArr" [ngValue]="x.id">
            {{ x.value }}
        </option>
    </select>
</tr>
```

This always **pre-selects** dropdown values as:

[image]

However, The dropdown should have values **pre-selected** as:

[image]

Comment: seems like working fine https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6jwkct?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: @SachilaRanawaka , Yes it is but in some browser it won't work

Comment: @SachilaRanawaka - the screenshot is from an actual application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It causes the issue when you use same name for all input what you can do is

Use `ngFor` `index` and then create dynamic name for `select` input like :

```
<tr *ngFor="let t of testVal;let i = index;">
    <select name = "test{{i}}" [(ngModel)] = "t.id">
```

**[WORKING DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-select-same-name)**

( You can test it in your browser as it will aslo work with same input name in latest chrome and firefox )

Comment: Looks like "same name" was causing the issue. This fixed it.
By the way I am on Version 65.0.3325.181 (Official Build) (64-bit) where it wasn't working.

Comment: @ManojNegi , It also depends on the OS , Great To know this solved your issue , Happy Coding BTW